# Problem with MikTex installation?

Tags: errors, miktex, installing

I downloaded `Net Installer` from website, both `32bit` and `64bit`, downloaded complete MikTeX, started the wizard again but the moment I select Install MikTex and press Next wizard closes.

Does anyone know whats going on? I get no errors, setup just closes itself. Happens both with 32bit and 64 installer.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Disable your antivirus during installation. The native Windows antivirus will activate and will not interfere with the installation of MikTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Once all the MiKTeX files are downloaded, check inside the containing folder. There will be a new identical installer. Run it and this time it will work.

Just look inside the folder where you downloaded your MikTeX files, you will find the installer as `setup-4.0-x64`, identical to the one you downloaded from the MiKTeX page. Or in case it doesn't exist, you can simply try dragging the installer to the folder.

[image: The setup]